# File is not including and require

Tags: php

I include a file in my php document but on local side and on server side it is not including i use require but it is also not working and an error show on the screen.. I checked the path 100 times it is right. The error is this:

`Warning: require(../library/config.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/logics/public_html/clients/creativecellutions/farnelo/files/header.php on line 3`

`Warning: require(../library/config.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/logics/public_html/clients/creativecellutions/farnelo/files/header.php on line 3`

`Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../library/config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/logics/public_html/clients/creativecellutions/farnelo/files/header.php on line 3`

Please help me to resolve this.

This is my code:

```
<?php 
require ("../library/config.php");
require ("../library/functions.php");
?>
```

Comment: Post your `include/require` code here

Comment: errors like that are allways a path issue or a permission issue check your path and that the file can be read

Comment: <?php 
require ("../library/config.php");
require ("../library/functions.php");
?>

Comment: check your path ../library/config.php....

Comment: path is right. I checked many times with different ways.

Comment: your code will try to include a file located at /home/logics/public_html/clients/creativecellutions/farnelo/library/config.php are you sure that is the currect location of the file?

Comment: yes it is the correct location

Answer (score 0):

```
 require(../library/config.php)
```

Is pointing to the wrong location in your directory. Get the location of config.php relative to the position of the file this script is calling. That should resolve the error.

Comment: Dude i said that i checked several times the position of the file is 100% correct, that's why i am confuse, otherwise i don't need to put my query on that forum.

Answer (score 0):

your code will try to include a file located at

`/home/logics/public_html/clients/creativecellutions/farnelo/library/config.php`

are you sure that is the currect location of the file?

if it is then the only ussue possible is that you do not have permission to read the file with php.

Comment: yes the path is correct, and if there is a permission issue, then what would i do?? please tell me. There is a url rewriting method is applied on this site.

Comment: the only other thing i can think of is that the files config.php has an uppercase letter somewhere, file names are case sensitive so make sure it is written EXACTLY as the path i posted

Comment: as far as permissions go it depends on the server OS, if it is a unix based machine then you need to use chmod command something like chmod 777 config.php

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not directly running `clients/creativecellutions/farnelo/files/header.php` and including this in some other file `index.php` or something else and that's where the problem may be.
Try using relative path `require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../library/config.php' );`

Answer (score 0):

Try using getcwd() function.

That is

```
include(getcwd()."path to config.php");
```